# How to load model in CI 3 with HMVC?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, frameworks, hmvc

I'm using the framework CodeIgniter 3 with HMVC extension and I can't load model. When I try do it, I see next error: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Protection.

Model file (protection.php) placed at /application/modules/main/models/ and extends this code:

```
class Protection extends MX_Model
    { 
    function Protection()
    {
        parent::Model();
    }
    function check($val)
    {
        $tpl = "![^\w\d\s]*!";
        if(is_array($val))
        {
            foreach($val as $k => $v)
            {
                $val[$k] = preg_replace($tpl,"",$v);
            }
        }
        else
        {
                $val = preg_replace($tpl,"",$val);
        }
        return $val;
    }
}
```

Controller file placing at /application/modules/main/controllers/ with this code for load model and call her function:

```
$this->load->model('protection');
$gj = "I'--m_Y%ou#r-Fat/+her";
$this->prt->check($gj);
echo $gj;
```

I tried rename model file, place his in other folders, but all it was failed.

Comment: Please provide your file structure. You can use this site to create your file structure as text: **http://www.FileStructureGenerator.com**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HMVC **models** should extend CI_Model only the controller use MX_ on controller  And also for a model name instead of just having protection as model name I think would be best to have model_protection so codeigniter will not get confused.

```
modules > 

modules > main >

modules > main > controllers

modules > main > models

modules > main > views
```

**On the constructor**

Not use `parent::Model();`

But use `parent::__construct();` Like in my example

**On controller**

```
$this->load->model('modulename/model_protection');

$this->model_protection->check($key);
```

**File name Model_protection.php**

```
<?php 

class Model_protection extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {

parent::__construct();

}

public function check($val) {

}

}
```

Tip all controllers and models and libraries should have there first letter as uppercase on file name and classname

Comment: How can get rid of typing module_name in 
$this->load->model('modulename/model_protection');